# Migrating SQL Database to php my admin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to transfer a SQL Database to a phpMyAdmin on a site. When I import the files, it gives me a lot of errors during analysis like this:

Unexpected character. (near "" at position 0)

Unexpected character. (near "" at position 1)

Unexpected character. (near "" at position 2)

Unexpected character. (near "" at position 3)

Unexpected character. (near "" at position 4)

... and so on.

What extension has to have the files?

Comment: I would really suggest you to create database in phpmyadmin and add tables one by one. Because here we can't tell you the errors without looking into your file

Comment: Ok. Thank you :)